# "specified network name is no longer available" when working with Jackcess

Tags: java, jackcess

I am trying to write a simple Java program to extract the tables and columns from Access databases. Using the Jackcess cookbook I've got the following:

```
        String sourceDatabase = "C:\\temp\\test1.mdb";
        Database accessDB = DatabaseBuilder.open(new File(sourceDatabase));

        // Loop through the tables
        Set<String> accessTables = accessDB.getTableNames();
        for (String currentTable: accessTables) {
            System.out.println("Reading table " + currentTable + "...");

            Table table = accessDB.getTable(currentTable); // This is line 51 where the stacktrace occurs

            // Loop through columns in current table
            for(Column column : table.getColumns()) {
                String columnName = column.getName();

                Integer colType = column.getSQLType();


                Boolean isAutoNumber = column.isAutoNumber();

                System.out.println("\t" + columnName + " \t" + sqlTypeToText(colType) + "\t" + isAutoNumber);

            }

            System.out.println("");


        }
        accessDB.close();
```

However when I try to run it I get the following output with stacktrace:

```
Reading table _OracletblColumn...
    colid   8   false
    tblid   8   false
    colname     12  false
    dbid    8   false

Reading table _OracletblDatabase...
    dbid    8   false
    dbname  12  false
    dbpathname  12  false

Reading table _OracletblTable...
    tblid   8   false
    dbid    8   false
    tblname     12  false

Reading table DICT_ACCOM...
java.io.IOException: The specified network name is no longer available
    at sun.nio.ch.FileDispatcher.pread0(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.FileDispatcher.pread(FileDispatcher.java:35)
    at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.readIntoNativeBuffer(IOUtil.java:195)
    at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.read(IOUtil.java:171)
    at sun.nio.ch.FileChannelImpl.read(FileChannelImpl.java:612)
    at com.healthmarketscience.jackcess.impl.PageChannel.readPage(PageChannel.java:211)
    at com.healthmarketscience.jackcess.impl.TempPageHolder.setPage(TempPageHolder.java:86)
    at com.healthmarketscience.jackcess.impl.TempPageHolder.setPage(TempPageHolder.java:74)
    at com.healthmarketscience.jackcess.impl.UsageMap$ReferenceHandler.<init>(UsageMap.java:693)
    at com.healthmarketscience.jackcess.impl.UsageMap$ReferenceHandler.<init>(UsageMap.java:673)
    at com.healthmarketscience.jackcess.impl.UsageMap.initHandler(UsageMap.java:146)
    at com.healthmarketscience.jackcess.impl.UsageMap.read(UsageMap.java:136)
    at com.healthmarketscience.jackcess.impl.UsageMap.read(UsageMap.java:108)
    at com.healthmarketscience.jackcess.impl.TableImpl.<init>(TableImpl.java:245)
    at com.healthmarketscience.jackcess.impl.DatabaseImpl.readTable(DatabaseImpl.java:1538)
    at com.healthmarketscience.jackcess.impl.DatabaseImpl.readSystemCatalog(DatabaseImpl.java:849)
    at com.healthmarketscience.jackcess.impl.DatabaseImpl.<init>(DatabaseImpl.java:526)
    at com.healthmarketscience.jackcess.impl.DatabaseImpl.open(DatabaseImpl.java:393)
    at com.healthmarketscience.jackcess.DatabaseBuilder.open(DatabaseBuilder.java:252)
    at com.healthmarketscience.jackcess.DatabaseBuilder.open(DatabaseBuilder.java:291)
    at com.healthmarketscience.jackcess.util.LinkResolver$1.resolveLinkedDatabase(LinkResolver.java:42)
    at com.healthmarketscience.jackcess.impl.DatabaseImpl.getTable(DatabaseImpl.java:1003)
    at com.healthmarketscience.jackcess.impl.DatabaseImpl.getTable(DatabaseImpl.java:971)
    at com.healthmarketscience.jackcess.impl.DatabaseImpl.getTable(DatabaseImpl.java:929)
    at com.healthmarketscience.jackcess.impl.DatabaseImpl.getTable(DatabaseImpl.java:82)
    at com.ralph.sql.test1.migrateTableDefs(test1.java:51)
    at com.ralph.sql.test1.main(test1.java:24)
```

I've tried googling but haven't found anyone else having the same problem with Jackcess, what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On further investigation discovered the code above is not at fault.

When I moved the Access database to a different folder the code above works perfectly without stacktracing. My first thought was file permissions, I checked my user had read/write access to the database (and the C:\temp folder) which it did.

Turned out it was my corporate virus scan (McAfee) doing some sort of on access scan that was breaking it. As I am not allowed to disable the virus scanner, I'm going to move all my work into folders inside C:\users\username as the virus scan allows me to access these. So much for having local admin permission, it didn't help.